# Getting UTC offset of system time zone on Mac (C++)

Tags: c++, macos, time, macos-carbon, core-foundation

I'm trying to get the system time zone expressed as an offset from UTC in minutes - something like the Windows function GetTimeZoneInformation(LPTIME_ZONE_INFORMATION). Is there something in Corefoundation or Carbon that could give me this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [Date and Time Programming Guide for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDatesAndTimes/Tasks/UsingDates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001141-CJBEHAAG).

This is untested, but how about:

```
CFTimeZoneRef tz = CFTimeZoneCopySystem();
CFTimeInterval minsFromGMT = CFTimeZoneGetSecondsFromGMT(tz, CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()) / 60.0;
CFRelease(tz);
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I missed that article with my frantic Googling.

Comment: Brilliant. You must have neck pains from carrying such a huge brain.

Comment: @Duck thanks, but I probably nicked the solution from someone else...